# Weird issue with querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using .NET 4 at my side. While working with my project I noticed a weird issue with querystring. When I am trying to access the following url:

```
http://localhost:43173/section/pages?userid=1&username=aa
```

I am not able to get any of the query string parameters. But when I add the "/" slash after the "pages" in the above url

```
http://localhost:43173/section/pages?userid=1&username=aa
```

I am able to get querystring params. I am just trying to access the querystring via `HttpContext.Current.Request["userid"]`
Can you tell me why it is behaving so?

Comment: May I know why downvote for my question? I noticed this issue that's why I asked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because "pages" is a web folder. If you had something like

```
http://localhost:43173/section/pages/page1.aspx?userid=1&username=aa
```

it would work without the slash.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It's your extensionless URLs. The framework delimits with the `/` so it thinks the resource you're calling is called `pages?userid=1&username=aa`</strike>

Is there a reason you can't just include the final slash?

Edit: I've just put together a toy site and my routes work fine, edit your post to show your route configuration, I'm guessing your problem is in there.

Comment: I doubt it. `?` is the query string separator regardless.

Answer (score 0):

do you use Routing? it seems like you do because the sample you gave doesnt have a `.aspx` extension. if you do, kindly post your routes, Im very sure thats the problem.